# Is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions, needs-more-focus

As a follower of the [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme) tag, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28665000/465378), which was closed as too broad. The question body in its entirety is simply the following:

> Is it possible to update the program code while it is being interpreted by **csi**, the Chicken Scheme Interpreter? If so, how?

To me, this feels like a pretty specific problem, even if the question itself is fairly short.

I'm not making the claim that this question *isn't* too broad—I haven't yet cast a reopen vote—but if it *is* too broad, I'd be interested in understanding why this sort of question isn't valid on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think [jmac's puzzle analogy may be apropos here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/).

It looks like a medium-to-large sized task/subject, and it's impossible to tell which pieces the asker already understands. I will note that I can't be certain of the breadth of the problem, since *I* don't know how to do what's being asked, either. But the "too broad" seems appropriate as a defense against either an enormous dissertation of an answer, or an endless comment exchange to fill in all the gaps that the asker either ignored or was ignorant of. Neither of those things generally **leave behind a truly useful document** for future searchers even if they have the same problem.

If you know that it isn't as large a problem as it seems at first glance, by all means vote to reopen.